# Slice rows together

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

[image]

HI,

as you can see in the image I want to make one row out of the 4 rows. Every set of values has got the same ordernumber.

Comment: I can't quite see what you're trying to do.  What four rows are you trying to combine? Can you show sample expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I mocked up a dataset to look like yours:

[image]

You're going to need a way to group the rows.  You can use a value in your dataset if you have one handy or build up your own like this:  Add an index.  Divide the index by the number or rows in each 'row group' and then truncate the result to an integer.  Play a little with the starting number on your index to get the rounding to put your grouping numbers where you need them.

[image]

Use the 'Group By' button in power query -- you can find it in the Home and the Transform ribbons.  Group by that value that the rows share.  Create an aggregate for each column and use the 'max' aggregation.  This will take the non-null value from each rowset.

[image]

VOILA!

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was almost there. This is  the last step I was looking for. This really helped me.

Comment: I also thought about the group by function but I didn't think about the MAX operation

Comment: Yes...the use of MAX *is* quite insightful. I like how straightforward this solution is.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with this as the source:

[image]

Click on [image] and type `Table.FromColumns({List.RemoveNulls(Source[Voorvehandeling]),List.RemoveNulls(Source[Proces]),List.RemoveNulls(Source[Laagdikte]),List.RemoveNulls(Source[Kleur])},{"Voorvehandeling","Proces","Laagdikte","Kleur"})`

That's it:

[image]

My M code is:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Custom1 = Table.FromColumns({List.RemoveNulls(Source[Voorvehandeling]),List.RemoveNulls(Source[Proces]),List.RemoveNulls(Source[Laagdikte]),List.RemoveNulls(Source[Kleur])},{"Voorvehandeling","Proces","Laagdikte","Kleur"})
in
Custom1
```

Comment: This is cool.  I didn't see your answer here when I did mine.  But what happens if one of those values were null?  Like the 50 micron field was actually empty.  Would the whole Laagdikte column be frame shifted up?

Comment: Yes @Ryan. It *would* shift up. That's a good thing be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

And here's yet one more approach that remedies the issue that @Ryan pointed out in my earlier answer.

I started with this:

[image]

*Note that Laagdikte doesn't have an entry for the first set of four rows, which will become the first record. This is to illustrate that intentional nulls are accommodated.*

Then I added an index. ...And then I added a Modulo:

[image] 
[image]

Then I changed the code that the GUI made for the modulo. I changed it from `Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"Index", each Number.Mod(_, 4), type number}})` to `Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Modulo", each Number.Mod([Index], Table.ColumnCount(Source)), type number)`. *This changes the setting from a hard-coded 4 to a count of the table's columns.*

[image]

Then I added a column with this code: `if [Modulo] = 0  then [Index] else null`, which happens to be the same as adding a conditional column with these settings:

[image]

[image]

Then I selected the Custom column and filled down:

[image]

Then I grouped on the Custom column using count and then I edited the resulting code to this: `Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Custom"}, {{"Voorvehandeling", each List.RemoveNulls([Voorvehandeling]), type text}, {"Proces", each List.RemoveNulls([Proces]), type text}, {"Laagdikte", each List.RemoveNulls([Laagdikte]), type text}, {"Kleur", each List.RemoveNulls([Kleur]), type text}})`

[image]

Then I added another column with this code: `Table.FromColumns({[Voorvehandeling],[Proces],[Laagdikte],[Kleur]},{"Voorvehandeling","Proces","Laagdikte","Kleur"})`

[image]

Then I removed all but the new Tabled column:

[image]

And lastly I expanded the Table column:

[image]

*Note that the null in Laagdikte is accounted for.*

Oh... And my apologies for misspelling Voorbehandeling as Voorvehandeling throughout both answers. At least I was consistent. ;)

Here's the M code:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Inserted Modulo" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Modulo", each Number.Mod([Index], Table.ColumnCount(Source)), type number),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Modulo", "Custom", each if [Modulo] = 0  then [Index] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Custom"}, {{"Voorvehandeling", each List.RemoveNulls([Voorvehandeling]), type text}, {"Proces", each List.RemoveNulls([Proces]), type text}, {"Laagdikte", each List.RemoveNulls([Laagdikte]), type text}, {"Kleur", each List.RemoveNulls([Kleur]), type text}}),    
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Tabled", each Table.FromColumns({[Voorvehandeling],[Proces],[Laagdikte],[Kleur]},{"Voorvehandeling","Proces","Laagdikte","Kleur"})),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Tabled"}),
#"Expanded Tabled" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Tabled", {"Voorvehandeling","Proces","Laagdikte","Kleur"}, {"Voorvehandeling","Proces","Laagdikte","Kleur"})
in
#"Expanded Tabled"
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - If you are working in Power BI Desktop, click on the "Edit Queries" button in the Home ribbon. This will open the query editor.

2 - Hold down the Shift button on your keyboard, then click on the column headers for the columns you want to merge (in your case, I think you want Voorbehandling, Proces, Laagdikte, and Kleur). This should highlight/select all of the relevant columns.

3 - Click on the "Add Column" ribbon at the top of the page. Click on the "Merge Columns" button. This will bring up a dialogue box allowing you to specify how you want to merge your columns (add a delimiter, etc.)

[Click to see where to find the "Merge Columns" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOHAS.png)